# APNS: Not receving any feedback for registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: neither +/-

Tags: apple-push-notifications, token, device

I have been trying to use the default code in the iPhone APNS documentation to generate a device token using registerForRemoteNotificationTypes() but without succes.
Neither the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken or the didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError is called. I had placed a UIAlert in both these methods- both did not appear.

My iPhone is acceesing APNS using Wi/Fi using DHCP.(& am able to browse )
Is there any other setting that needs to to be done to genrate a device token?

can someone post a working code which can be used to generate device token?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:
The outgoing port 5223 had to be opened for the Firewall of my WiFi AP.

Comment: Solved: Try with Good iPhone device. :)